# find if part of previous line is equal to part of current line in Python

Tags: python, line, equals

I have a question about my code. I want to return a True if a specific part of my previous line is equal to the specific part in the current line (in this case the Z part). My file looks like this:

```
  G17 G3 X387.9385 Y200.0000 Z268.4040 R187.9385
  G17 G3 X200.0000 Y387.9385 Z268.4040 R187.9385
  G17 G3 X200.0000 Y387.9385 Z268.4040 R187.9385
  G17 G3 X200.0000 Y353.2089 Z328.5575 R153.2089
```

So in this case, I would like a True if the value after "Z" (268.4040) in line 2 is equal to that part in line 1. So that would be a True here. As soon as the value in the previous line isn't equal to the value in the current line, I would like a False. So that would be the case in line 4 (328.5575 is not equal to 268.4040). This file is named "pointZ.gcode" and has many lines. Can anybody help me with the Python code needed to return what I want? Thanks!

My code so far:

```
q = open("pointZ.gcode", "r")
searchlines = q.readlines()
file = ""
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "Z" in line:
        zp0 = map(str, searchlines[i+0].split()[4:5])
        zp1 = map(str, searchlines[i+1].split()[4:5])
        if zp0 == zp1:
            print("T")
        else:
            print("F")
```

This gives me the error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Where is your existing code?

Comment: It crashes because you're iterating over **all** lines and trying to access the next line (with the code `searchlines[i+1]`) but the last line **doesn't have** a next one. Modify your code to either start iterating at the 2nd line, or stop at the 2nd-to-last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution, doesn't read from the file but shows a basic algorithm that accumulates results in a list, list is length `N-1` where `N` is number of lines.

```
lines=['G17 G3 X387.9385 Y200.0000 Z268.4040 R187.9385',
  'G17 G3 X200.0000 Y387.9385 Z268.4040 R187.9385',
  'G17 G3 X200.0000 Y387.9385 Z268.4040 R187.9385',
  'G17 G3 X200.0000 Y353.2089 Z328.5575 R153.2089']

def lines_equal(curr_line, prev_line, compare_char):
   curr_line_parts = curr_line.split(' ')
   prev_line_parts = prev_line.split(' ')

   for item in zip(curr_line_parts, prev_line_parts):
       if item[0].startswith(compare_char):
           return item[0] == item[1]

results = []
prev_line = lines[0]

for line in lines[1:]:
    results.append(lines_equal(line, prev_line, 'Z'))
    prev_line = line

print(results)
```

Answer (score 2):

I will not post the code here, would like you to try . But will give you the hints:

```
1)Read the line from the file.
2) Split it on basis of " ".
3) The 4th element of the list is what you want. 
4) Now check it with previous string. You will need to maintain a variable where you will have to store the previous string. Initially it can be null. 
5) If it matches, print True else print False
```